# Selecting and modifying `if` statement with ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I want to update `if` statement in already existing class on particular line without changing the whole method.

Here is the target code (names of classes, methods and some code changed because they're not relevant):

```
public class Target extends Something {
   public Target(){
        super();
        //some code...
   }

    public Result targetMethod(Data firstPar, Data secondPar){
        if(someStatement()) {
            return Result.FAIL;
        } else {
            if(firstPar.check()){ //here is the line I want to change
                 firstPar.doSomething()
            }
            secondPar.doSomething();
            return Result.SUCCESS;
        }

    }
}
```

In this code I want to change `if(firstPar.check())` to something like this:

```
if(firstPar.check() && !Utilities.someOtherCheck(firstPar, secondPar))
```

Here is the way I tried to solve this:

```
ClassNode node = new ClassNode();
ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(bytes); //bytes - original target class
reader.accept(node, 0);
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
node.accept(cw);
MethodVisitor visitor = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "targetMethod", "<it's signature>", null, null);
visitor.visitCode();
//No idea what to do next
```

Things I don't understand:

1. How do I properly choose a line in MethodVisitor?
2. How do I change only a half of the `if` statement?
3. How do I get bytecode of the new class (which will be generated
   after we change target class)?

It would be nice if you could provide some kind of example code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question 1 is perhaps the most difficult. You'll need to find out the position to insert the instructions by recognizing some pattern. If you assume that `firstPar.check()` is called only once, then you can look for the following bytecode instructions for `if(firstPar.check())`:

```
ALOAD 1
INVOKEVIRTUAL Data.check ()Z
IFEQ L3
```

where `L3` is the jump label if `check` return `false`.

For question 2, notice that bytecode instructions for `if(firstPar.check() && !Utilities.someOtherCheck(firstPar, secondPar))` is:

```
ALOAD 1
INVOKEVIRTUAL Data.check ()Z
IFEQ L3
ALOAD 1
ALOAD 2
INVOKESTATIC Utilities.someOtherCheck (LData;LData;)Z
IFNE L3
```

So, you will need to insert 4 new instructions right after `IFEQ L3`.

You can do this by using the [Tree API](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/package-summary.html), where you create an adapter for `targetMethod` by subclassing `ClassVisitor` and `MethodNode`:

```
private static class ClassAdapter extends ClassVisitor {
    public ClassAdapter(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
            String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        if (name.equals("targetMethod"))
            return new MethodAdapter(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions, mv);
        else
            return mv;
    }
}

private static class MethodAdapter extends MethodNode {
    public MethodAdapter(int access, String name, String desc,
            String signature, String[] exceptions, MethodVisitor mv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        this.mv = mv;
    }
    // More to come ...
}
```

Inside `MethodAdapter`, you can override `visitEnd` to iterate all `instructions` inside the method, and try to detect the above 3 instructions and insert 4 new instructions after them:

```
@Override
public void visitEnd() {
    // Iterates all instructions in the method
    ListIterator<AbstractInsnNode> itr = instructions.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        // Checks whether the instruction is ALOAD 1
        AbstractInsnNode node = itr.next();
        if (node.getOpcode() != Opcodes.ALOAD
                || ((VarInsnNode) node).var != 1)
            continue;

        // Checks whether the next instruction is INVOKEVIRTUAL
        if (node.getNext() == null
                || node.getNext().getOpcode() != Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL)
            continue;

        // Checks the invoked method name and signature
        MethodInsnNode next = (MethodInsnNode) node.getNext();
        if (!next.owner.equals("Data")
                || !next.name.equals("check")
                || !next.desc.equals("()Z"))
            continue;

        // Checks whether the next of the next instruction is IFEQ
        AbstractInsnNode next2 = next.getNext();
        if (next2 == null
                || next2.getOpcode() != Opcodes.IFEQ)
            continue;

        // Creates a list instructions to be inserted
        InsnList list = new InsnList();
        list.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 1));
        list.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 2));
        list.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, 
            "Utilities", "someOtherCheck", 
            "(LData;LData;)Z", false));
        list.add(new JumpInsnNode(Opcodes.IFNE, ((JumpInsnNode) next2).label));

        // Inserts the list, updates maxStack to at least 2, and we are done
        instructions.insert(next2, list);
        maxStack = Math.max(2, maxStack);
        break;
    }
    accept(mv);
}
```

To use the adapter, you can chain it with a `ClassReader` and a `ClassWriter`. Below, I also chain a `TraceClassVisitor` to print out a log file in the tmp directory:

```
ClassReader reader = new ClassReader("Target");
ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(reader, 0);
TraceClassVisitor printer = new TraceClassVisitor(writer, 
        new PrintWriter(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + "Target.log"));
ClassAdapter adapter = new ClassAdapter(printer);
reader.accept(adapter, 0);
byte[] b = writer.toByteArray(); // The modified bytecode
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, works like a charm! Btw what does this zero in `ClassWriter` constructor and `reader#accept` method means? There is no flag with 0 value. Is that just a default behavior?

Comment: @RedEnergy They are options when writing and reading. You're right, 0 is the default behavior. In fact, you just pointed out a bug. :-) I should have also updated `maxStack` to be at least `2`, to make sure that the stack is big enough for the arguments of `someOtherCheck`. See edit: I added a line.