# How to find if statements in java method using javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I need to analyze a java method body at runtime. javassist provides a lot methods helping me to do this. But now I need to know if a given method contains if statements or loops. How can I achive this?

Most questions could be answered using

```
method.instrument(new ExprEditor() {
    @Override
    public void edit(MethodCall m) {
        // do some checks
    }
});
```

But there is no edit-Method for branches or loops.
What I tried so far:

```
for (CodeIterator ci = method.getMethodInfo().getCodeAttribute().iterator(); ci.hasNext();) {
    int op = ci.next();
    System.out.println(Mnemonic.OPCODE[op]);
}
```

Hoped to find some `if_*` or `goto`. But didn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I tried myself to have a **fine grain analysis of methods in Javassist** and I found that is **really, really hard** if not impossible.

Anyway at my time I found [this](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/tree/master/src/main/javassist/bytecode/analysis), a project in Java with a well structured Javassist analyzer. If you follow the link to the interesting package on github. Take a close look to classes `ControlFlow.java` first and then to 'Analyzer.java'. Here you can find some cool stuff done with Javassist.

When I was in your position I tried hard to solve my problems but I surrended to the fact that Javassist is not build for super fine grained analysis of the bytecode, so I dug up some more and I found that there is another library that is more suitable to this task: **ASM**. On its [website](http://asm.ow2.org/) you can find some tutorial about it if you are interested.

NB: with this tool is feasible to actually analize your class branch by branch or even line by line.

Comment: Can you give us an example to explain how asm find the if statements?

Comment: Try to checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066812/selecting-and-modifying-if-statement-with-asm